# Concatenate 2 JSON values and serialize JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, serialization

In my webform I have an input field and I want to take input from the user and concatenate with my onw value like user input **123**, my value **test** and the final result that would be send with the POST to be **test123**. What should I do, how to do this?

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="test" name="test">
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#formid").length) {
        $("#formid").submit(function(event) {
            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: form.serialize(),
                //success...
```

Comment: If the value is always going to be amended, it makes more sense to keep the client side for direct user input and then update the received values as necessary on the server side.

Comment: Easiest option is to add `<input type='hidden' name='test' value='test'>` inside your `<form>` then it will be serialise()'d and posted with the form then handle it server-side.

Comment: An alternative would be to have (again) a hidden input, but update it via javascript every time `#test` changes - but seems like it would be more prone to issues.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I use Elasticsearch to store this data and it would be harder to this there :(
Maybe a concatenation before serialization or right when data is serialized..but idk how to do it

Comment: I used this `data: $(this).serialize() + '&NonFormValue=' + NonFormValue,` but it only adds one more value to the test input

Comment: If you're *prepending* your own value, then you *could* add it after serialize(), eg `var data = form.serialize(); data = data.replace(/^(test=)/, "$1test")`  https://jsfiddle.net/12b3x0kf/  (`^` assumes this is the only/first field as in the example) (adding it after would just need a different regex) - example user value of `"123"` becomes `test=test123`